# Is a Threadpool Threadsafe when accessed by mutliple instances?

Tags: java, thread-safety

I am currently working on a osgi framework, and came across a point of inquery:

When you instantiate multiple instances of a class, (for example via a factory), which will  create tasks and give them to workerthreads originating out of the same threadpool, Do I need to make the calls from those instances to that Threadpool Threadsafe?

**EDIT** This is my code for the ThreadPool:

```
    public class JournalThreadPool{

        private static ExecutorService executor;

        private JournalThreadPool(){
        }

        public static ExecutorService getUniqueInstance(){
            if(executor == null)
                executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
            return executor;
        }   
    }
```

And I have multiple Threads who create a task, and assign the task to one of the Threads from this ThreadPool like so:

```
    JournalThreadPool.getUniqueInstance().execute(RunnableTask);
```

Can this generate conflicts? for example, when 2 threads try to execute their task at the same time?

Comment: Commenting on the thread-safety of unknown code is, well, impossible. Show us your code.

Comment: I haven't written any code yet, I basically need to know if need to sychronize the call: ExecutorService.execute(workerThread) when this call will originate from multiple instances (In a multithreaded way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to make shared, mutable data threads safe.

I suggest you avoid having the constructors share any mutable data and you won't have a problem.

If you have such shared data, I suggest you make access to the data via thread safe methods, i.e. don't access the data directly.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance no but all of this depends on if your factory has a common shared data between all calls (e.g. numberOfEntities). If there are no race conditions in you factory or code spawning the workers you are safe.

If you provide more code we could further comment....